# How to convert HTMLElement to its tag name

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have an array of different HTMLElement tags such as HTMLParagraphElement, HTMLDivElement and etc.

Is there a way to convert HTMLParagraphElement to 'p' or simply compare them somehow?

Basically I'm looking for a way to compare, so statements like HTMLDivElement === "div", HTMLParagraphElement === "p" become true.

```
function findTag(tagName) {
  const nodes = []
  
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

  for (let i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
      // here i'm trying to compare tag to an HTMLElement. 
      // If it corresponds such as 'p' = HTMLParagraphElement, I want to push it into 'nodes' array.
  }
  
  return nodes
}

console.log(findTag('p'));
```

Comment: Why not returning directly `document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)`?

Comment: I'm trying to comprehend the implementation of `.getElementsByTagName`. Even though using `.getElementsByTagName` itself is redundant, I still want to know the answer :)

Comment: For 1, `getElementsByTagName()` isn't written in JS. Then it doesn't target only HTMLElements, but any Element (and it doesn't treat the ones in the HTML namespace the same way as others. The specs are at https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-getelementsbytagname

Answer (score 1):

There is a tagName property of each element.

E.g.

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName("*")].filter(t=>t.tagName===tagName)
```

As someone commented, you could more simply just do:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
```

Note that the tagNames will be uppercase, e.g. `P` instead of `p`.

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about `tagName` property for some reason. Even though I have it in my code as a parameter name.

Comment: @RomaKim the doc on this is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName